# Помогите разобраться с retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

Здравствуйте. В приложении используется библиотека retrofit.
Имеется

```
public interface ServerAPI {
@Headers({"Authorization: Test_Token {accessToken}"})
@GET("xxxxx/profile")
Call<Response> getProfile(@Body ProfileRequest profileRequest, String token);
}
```

Так вот, мне надо вместо "accessToken" подставить переменную token , но я не знаю как это реализовать, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Аргумент `@Header("accessToken") String accessToken`?

Comment: Вы были почти правы, нужно было убрать @Headers, и в getProfile добавить "@Header("Authorization") String accesToken", где accesToken это строка вида "Test_Token 34dfhdfhds24234dfsdf", в итоге получается заголовок Authorization: Test_Token 34dfhdfhds24234dfsdf"

Answer (score 3):

Что бы не добавлять к каждому методу заголовок лучше создать специальный interceptor который будет автоматически сам добавлять этот заголовок с токеном.

Для этого сначала создаем класс который будет реализовывать интерфейс `Interceptor`

```
public class TokenInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {

        Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", "Test_Token " + accesToken) // добавляем заголовок в запрос
                .build()

        return chain.proceed(request);
    }   
}
```

Далее надо создать объект `OkHttpClient` и добавить в него interceptor

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(new TokenInterceptor())
    .build();
```

После чего осталось добавить наш client к ретрофиту

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .client(client)
    .baseUrl("base_url")
    .build();
```

После этого в каждый запрос будет добавляться заголовок с токеном. Так же это позволит динамически менять токен во время работы приложения, если например он протух и его надо обновить. Для этого только надо хранить экземпляр interceptora который установлен в ретрофите и каким либо образом передавать в него новый токен.